# May a Linux kernel package have config files that remain in storage after removing the package?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, purge

Is there any use in purging a kernel package, instead of removing? I ask this, because automatic removal of packages does not purge all packages it removes. (I have setup this automatic removing in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, and it is said to be equivalent to `apt-get autoremve`) At least `dpkg-query -L` for such a package gives

```
Package 'linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic' does not contain any files (!)
```

so it would suggest there are no config files lying around. `dpkg-query` shows status `deinstall ok config-files` for `linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic`. For the respective header package `linux-headers-4.2.0-21-generic`, `dpkg-query` shows status `not-installed`, and for `linux-headers-4.2.0-21` it does not show a match after the automatic removal operation.

For what it is worth, here is an extract of `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log`:

```
Removing linux-headers-4.2.0-21-generic (4.2.0-21.25) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.2.0-21 (4.2.0-21.25) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-21-generic (4.2.0-21.25) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.2.0-21-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.2.0-21-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.2.0-21-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.2.0-21-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
Removing linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic (4.2.0-21.25) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

No `linux-{image,image-extra,header}-<version>-generic` package adds anything to `/etc`. You can confirm this using a quick check of currently installed kernel packages:

```
grep /etc /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-{image,headers}*.list
```

The output will be nothing. This is also reinforced by the lack of `.conffiles` for these packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`. As such, you don't need to purge these packages; removing and purging are effectively the same for kernel packages.

What does remain after you remove these packages is information that `dpkg` itself stores (in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`): the `postrm` [package maintainer script](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), list of files, etc. The last step in purging is running `postrm` *and* deleting `postrm` itself (and any other information `dpkg` might have, such as file lists) - which is not usually done for normal removal. You might see a bunch of `linux-image*.postrm` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.

Comment: Well, at least there is a difference in status for some of these packages in the dpkg database.

Comment: That is explained in the question.

Comment: I mean packages.

Comment: No, both header packages were installed before automatic removal.

Comment: Ah, I get it. That's because the kernel image packages have [package maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) (in particular, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package-name>.postrm`). The last step in purging is running `postrm` *and* deleting `postrm` itself (and any other information `dpkg` might have, such as file lists) - which is not usually done for normal removal. You might see a bunch of `linux-image*.postrm` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.

Comment: Well, I can see them for installed kernels only; I purged the removed kernel packages already.

Comment: And you're still seeing `config-files` in `dpkg-query`'s output for those packages?

Comment: No, not anymore after the purge command.